# Chinese characters showing incorrectly in html page

Tags: html

Hi I started in creating an html page with Chinese characters.

I used W3 schools try it page as a reference to what i am doing, I simply put the code in their try it window and see my output.

The thing is that i used this code

```css
    <style> .block1 {
      color: #0000ff;
      /*display: block;*/
      font-family: 宋体：SimSun font-size: 1.41667em;
      font-weight: bold;
      line-height: 1.2;
      margin-bottom: 0.67em;
      margin-left: 0;
      margin-right: 0;
      margin-top: 24pt;
      /* page-break-inside: avoid;*/
    }
    .calibre {
      color: #4F81BD;
      display: block;
      font-family: "細明體", sans-serif;
      font-size: 1em;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      margin-left: 5pt;
      margin-right: 5pt;
      margin-top: 0;
      padding-left: 0;
      padding-right: 0
    }
    .block2 {
      color: red;
      display: block;
      font-family: "細明體", sans-serif;
      margin-bottom: 3pt;
      margin-left: 0;
      margin-right: 0;
      margin-top: 3pt;
      padding-bottom: 0;
      padding-left: 0;
      padding-right: 0;
      padding-top: 0;
      text-align: justify
    }
    </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <h1 class="block1">嗨 hhh</h1>

  <p class="block2">（卷上）</p>

</body>

</html>
```

But no matter what i give in font family, the chinese characters are not showing in the output page

Somebody please help only 'hhh' is coming, chinese characters are showing as '?'..

Edit to add is that the code is working fine in firefox browser, but not working in chrome, why? because the code has to be independent of browser right?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `meta` tag. Try using `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in your head.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- Styles, Javascript and other things go here -->
</head>
```

Comment: i did, but same result

Comment: can you post me the code here? also can you post the same in this link and see what happens. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_font-family

Comment: one more thing the code is working fine in firefox, but it is not working in chrome why?